# Not getting jobtitle from linkedin integration in android?

Tags: android, linkedin-api

I'm try to integrate my App with linkedin and i'm using this [source code](http://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/wiki/Linkedin).

**I m getting all info except get job title.**

also make API and SECRET KEY

http://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/wiki/Linkedin

also work so many link but facing error.

Comment: Hi HCD, you can modify socialauth source code. If you need any help please let me know.

Comment: yes if can then tell me how can i get jobtitle bcz this code is so simple and value able for me so plz will u tell me????

Comment: Hi , will reply you on mail u sent.